# how to pass the case id from controller to visualforce page

Tags: controller, visualforce

I am creating a case by initiating in the controller. I need to pass the case id for attaching the attachment through vf page. Please provide the syntax to do that.

**Edit:** Code added

```
Case c = new Case (mandatory fields); 
insert c; 
//I need to pass the Caseid (c.Id) to visualforce page . For eg : I need to get this value in 

<apex:outputlabel>
```

Comment: Edit your question and include the source from your controller class

Comment: Case c = new Case (mandatory fields);
insert c;

I need to pass the Caseid (c.Id) to visualforce page . For eg : I need to get this value in <apex:outputlabel>

Comment: you can make this case variable public using get set and then direct reference it in the page.

Comment: can u pls provide me the syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:outputlabel value={!myid}>
```

**Apex :**

```
Case c = new Case (mandatory fields); 
insert c;

public ID myid = c.id;
```